# Why is my ActionBar missing?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a new activity in android, but in this activity the ActionBar seems to be missing. I created the activity and the layout according to some other activity, in which the title is shown correctly.

Here is the code if the activity:

```
public class SelectRoute extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_route);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.selectroute_view);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

and here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/select_route"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.impyiablue.checkpoint.SelectRoute">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/selectroute_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Complete manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.impyiablue.checkpoint"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CheckScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_check"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".SelectRoute"
            android:label="@string/title_select_route"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why is the title bar and the title not shown? In the Preview of AndroidStudio it is shown. Seems to be a bug somewhere...

Comment: If you're talking about the `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`, there is no `Toolbar` in that layout, and you're using a `NoActionBar` theme.

Comment: I mean the thing at the top of the screen, just below the bar with the notification, clock etc, where e.g. the application name is shown

Comment: post also ALL of your manifest

Comment: The app's name is normally shown in the `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`.

Comment: Then I probably mean the `ActionBar` / `Toolbar`. Is there a difference?

Comment: There is no toolbar in your xml layout which you referenced in your code. Am wondering how it even compiled to run. Solution is to add the toolbar to your xml.

Comment: I probably meant the ActionBar

Comment: An `ActionBar` used to be "built-in" to an `Activity`'s decor, and had a bunch of specialized behavior, but they're kinda moving away from that. `Toolbar` is available now as a more flexible alternative, as it's just a regular `View`, but you can set one as a support `ActionBar` in the support libraries, to maintain some of the old patterns. However, you have to provide a `<Toolbar>` in the layout to be able to set it as an `ActionBar`, and you have to disable the `ActionBar` that's provided by default, which is what the `NoActionBar` theme is doing here already.

Comment: I just want to display a simple title, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code

```
<activity
    android:name=".CheckScreen"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_check"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
<activity
    android:name=".SelectRoute"
    android:label="@string/title_select_route"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

To this

```
<activity
    android:name=".CheckScreen"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_check"/>
<activity
    android:name=".SelectRoute"
    android:label="@string/title_select_route"/>
```

Comment: Well, in the activity 'CheckSreen' the title is shown

Comment: From your theme you are setting the both activity theme as `noActionBar`. so this will remove the action bar of your activity. And the reason where you getting the action bar You may created an action bar in your xml @Alex

Comment: @Alex remove these line from your code `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`
        `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: It does not change anything. Also not sure we are talking about the correct bar. I mean the top top one, directly below the bar with nofifications, time tc, which normally contain the name of the app

Comment: @Alex these two are not required. Currently you are trying to access n undefined variable R.id.toolbar from that activity. i cant find any id called toolbar in your xml

Comment: But I have this in the 'other' activity. When I remove this lines in the other activity, the Toolbar/ActionBar will vanish in the OTHER activity...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157748/discussion-between-alex-and-sushin-pv).

Comment: You cannot access an id that is not defined in its context currently you are setting `setContentView(R.layout.select_route);`. in this xml there is no toolbar. Just remove both the theme from your manifest and then if you are not creating a custom action bar you dont need to set is separately

Comment: Ok, so I am ABSOLUTELY confused now. I have two activities. For activity A I need to specify a theme in the manifest to display the ActionBar. But if I use the EXACT same theme for the other activity B, there is no action-bar. 

This is not logic

Comment: @Alex to display an ActionBar you don't need to specify the theme separately. Default it will be show. Please paste the code in your `value > style > AppTheme`. May be you added same unwanted code here

Comment: @Alex If you want to display the default ActionBar you don't have to create a ActionBar in your xml as shows in the other answer

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Change your theme to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

The android studio previews layout using the theme you have selected in the option.

Answer (score 0):

Add the toolbar to your xml file.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/select_route"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.impyiablue.checkpoint.SelectRoute">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/selectroute_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No need to. I have a DIFFERENT activity which is coded VERY SIMILAR to the faulty one. But this other activity does not have the `Toolbar` stuff in it

Comment: The reason simply is that the "activity" uses a different theme from the "faulty one". From your manifest, the activity affected are the `SelectRoute` and the `CheckScreen`.